# Faster way to store a NLTK FreqDict?

Tags: python, json, serialization, nltk, pickle

I'm trying to speed up my application, and I discovered that the simple little function below (compute_ave_freq), is actually one of the biggest time hogs. The culprit seems to be when it unpickles an NLTK FreqDist; it takes an obscene amount of time.

Of course, even that obscene amount of time is less than half of what it would take to compute the FreqDist anew. Is there any better way to save an NLTK FreqDist object? I tried serializing it as JSON, but that saves it as a simple dictionary, losing a lot of the NLTK functionality that I need.

Here's the code:

```
def compute_ave_freq(word_forms):    
    fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))
    total_freq = 0
    for form in word_forms:
        freq = fd.freq(form)
        total_freq += freq
    try:
        ave_freq = total_freq/len(word_forms)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        ave_freq = 0
    return ave_freq
```

And here's the LineProfiler output:

```
Total time: 0.197121 s
File: /home/username/development/appname/filename.py
Function: compute_ave_freq at line 25
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
25                                           def compute_ave_freq(word_forms, debug=False):
26                                               # word_forms is a list of morphological variations of a word, such as
27                                               # ['كتبوا', 'كتبو', 'كتبنا', 'كتبت']
28                                           
29         1        78580  78580.0     79.1      fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))
30         1            3      3.0      0.0      total_freq = 0
31         5           10      2.0      0.0      for form in word_forms:
32         4        20676   5169.0     20.8          freq = fd.freq(form)
33         4            9      2.2      0.0          if debug==True:
34                                                       print(form, '\n', freq)
35         4            6      1.5      0.0          total_freq += freq
36         1            1      1.0      0.0      try:
37         1            3      3.0      0.0          ave_freq = total_freq/len(word_forms)
38                                               except ZeroDivisionError:
39                                                   ave_freq = 0
40         1            1      1.0      0.0      return ave_freq
```

Thanks!

Comment: Unpickling is loading to RAM and that's a rather hard issue to handle but once it's loaded it's fine. Possibly, putting it into some DB (e.g. SQL/Mongo) would be a better way to work with bigger datasets. Otherwise, just wait for a while for it to load onto the RAM.

Comment: I think the general rule can be that "If you have a dataset that can be loaded onto the RAM fully without much strain, then it's not really that big and time saved on indexing/querying DB might not be substantial".

Comment: Move `fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))` outside the function and simply pass it to the function if `fd` changes, i.e. `def compute_ave_freq(word_forms, fd):`. Othewise, if `fd` doesn't change, just make `fd` a global variable and load it once.

Comment: Thank you @alvas -- I think that's probably the best solution!

Comment: That really did do the trick — I made `fd` a global variable, and that improved the parse time for my sample sentence from 7.2 seconds to 2.0 seconds. I don't know why I didn't think of that before!

Comment: Glad that it helps =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, move the `fd` variable outside of the function should resolve the problem:

```
fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))

def compute_ave_freq(word_forms):    
    total_freq = 0
    for form in word_forms:
        freq = fd.freq(form)
        total_freq += freq
    try:
        ave_freq = total_freq/len(word_forms)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        ave_freq = 0
    return ave_freq
```

But since you're creating an sum-averaging function, here's a simpler implementation:

```
fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))

def compute_ave_freq(word_forms):
    try:
        return sum([fd.freq(form) for form in word_forms]) / len(word_forms)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
```

Or:

```
fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))

def compute_ave_freq(word_forms):
    l = len(word_forms)
    if  l > 0:
        return sum([fd.freq(form) for form in word_forms]) / l
    else:
        return 0
```

Or simpler:

```
fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))

def compute_ave_freq(word_forms):
    l = len(word_forms)
    return sum([fd.freq(form) for form in word_forms]) / l if l > 0 else 0
```

Or with `lambda`:

```
fd = pickle.load(open("data/fd.txt", 'rb'))
compute_ave_freq = lambda x: sum(fd.freq(i) for i in x)/len(x)
ave_freq = compute_ave_freq(word_forms) if len(word_forms) > 0 else 0
```

Do take a look at [EAFP and LBYL](https://github.com/usaarhat/pywarmups/blob/master/session4.md#forgiveness-and-leaping)

Comment: Thank you again, and thanks for the reference as well. I used the first variant you suggested (with the list comprehension), because `lambda`s make my head hurt ... :-)